# Failed InputSimulation - Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI) Error

Tags: c#, windows, inputsimulator

Hey i have written a software in C# and run it on a windows server 2019.

I trying to navigate with:

```
inputSimulator.Keyboard.KeyDown(WindowsInput.Native.VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
```

in the Explorer.

The Programm should run 1 year after the start.
And it works alltimes fine for 1 Day.
It does the same process in this 1 Day 3 Times and navigat 3 Times secessfull in the explorer and selected the right path and file.

But after 24 Hours it get an error by running the secound loop.

Error:
System.Exception: 'Some simulated input commands were not sent successfully. The most common reason for this happening are the security features of Windows including User Interface Privacy Isolation (UIPI). Your application can only send commands to applications of the same or lower elevation. Similarly certain commands are restricted to Accessibility/UIAutomation applications. Refer to the project home page and the code samples for more information.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was, that the user is logged out after i close my remotedesctop connection. And a logged out user cant perform an InputSimulation.

Comment: How did you solve the issue with user getting logged off with closing the RDP connection?